# pandas read_json for multi line jsons returns a JSONReader and not a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file `file1.json` whose contents are like this (each dict in a separate line):

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
{"c":3,"d":4}
{"e":9,"f":6}
.
.
.
{"u":31,"v":23}
{"w":87,"x":46}
{"y":98,"z":68}
```

I want to load this file into a pandas dataframe, so this is what i did:

```
df = pd.read_json('../Dataset/file1.json', orient='columns', lines=True, chunksize=10)
```

But this instead of returning a dataframe returns a JSONReader.

```
[IN]: df
[OUT]: <pandas.io.json.json.JsonReader at 0x7f873465bd30>
```

Is it normal, or am i doing something wrong? And if this is how read_json() is supposed to behave when there're multiple dictionaries in a single json file (without being any comma separated) and with each dict in a separate line, then how can i best fit them into a dataframe?

**EDIT**:
if i remove the `chunksize` paramter from the read_json() this is what i get:

```
[IN]: df = pd.read_json('../Dataset/file1.json', orient='columns', lines=True)
[OUT]: ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Comment: that's what `chunksize` does. see the doc: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-jsonl

Comment: thing is if i don't add the parameter chunksize it gives out an error as `ValueError: Expected object or value` also it doesn't recognize the file as valid json object as each dictionary is separated by a new line character

Comment: @AmanSingh It sounds like the problem with your other attempt is that you didn't use `lines=True`, so you were telling it that you had a single JSON text rather than a file full of line-delimited JSON texts, which isn't true, so it gives you an error. But if that's not it, create a new question.

Comment: @AmanSingh - are data confidental?

Comment: The problem does not happen with your sample input. If it happens with your real input, you have to figure out how to give us sample input that causes the same error, or we can't help you. But as I already told you, create a new question for a new problem, don't try to edit all of your problems into one question.

Comment: Actually, the problem _does_ happen with your sample input if I leave those `.` lines in. Are those actually in your real file?

Comment: @abarnet yes the data is confidential. I'll try recreating a new sample input dataset for new question. And no, the `...` aren't actually present in the actual dataset i added those to make it a understanding that there are many more such records in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) explain, this is exactly the point of the `chunksize` parameter:

> **chunksize: integer, default None**
>
> Return `JsonReader` object for iteration. See the [line-delimted json docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-jsonl) for more information on `chunksize`. This can only be passed if *lines=True*. If this is None, the file will be read into memory all at once.

The linked docs say:

> For line-delimited json files, pandas can also return an iterator which reads in `chunksize` lines at a time. This can be useful for large files or to read from a stream.

… and then give an example of how to use it.

If you don't want that, why are you passing `chunksize`? Just leave it out.

Comment: thing is if i don't add the parameter chunksize it gives out an error as `ValueError: Expected object or value`

Comment: @AmanSingh Then you have another error, and the `chunksize` was just masking it—you don't actually read anything, and therefore don't see the other error, until you `for chunk in reader:` or similar.

Comment: @AmanSingh `lines=True` makes it read JSON lines instead of a single JSON text. `chunksize=10` makes it _also_ give you a reader object that reads chunks of 10 lines at a time instead of the whole file. Just throwing random arguments at it until it seems to work isn't going to get you anywhere; read the docs.

Comment: @AmanSingh Meanwhile, if you need help debugging the other problem this one was masking, create a new question with a [mcve] for that question—the code that uses `lines` but not `chunksize`, sample input (ideally something we can copy and paste without removing the `...` lines in the middle), and the traceback—and you should get an answer to that one as well.

Comment: @abarnet I have added the output it gives when i try to read it as a whole into the memory. You could possibly be very right, the issue could be something else, but i'm not able to identify it. Pls check the edit

Comment: my answer is OK, `df = pd.concat(df)` working nice in my sample, do you test it?